# CSS animation stops working after repeating it several times

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you click repeatedly and very fast on the div it will stop doing the animation and the transform class won't get removed.
this is the code:

```js
let item = document.querySelector('.item');

item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  item.classList.add('transform');
});

item.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  item.classList.remove('transform');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #0b0a10;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.transform {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background-color: #fe960f;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="item">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I solve this and why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click right when the trasitionend event fires then the class animation class is added but theres no new trasitionend event because the animation has already finished.

My suggestion is not to use transitionend and instead set a timeout when you add the initial animation class with a callback that removes the class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what `MDN` says about `transitionend` event:

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed or display is set to none, then the event will not be generated.

Though you could  use the `toggle` function, like so:

```js
let item=document.querySelector('.item');

    item.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        item.classList.toggle('transform');
    });

    item.addEventListener('transitionend',function(e){
         item.classList.remove('transform');
    });
```

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #0b0a10;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item{
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    transition: 0.2s;
 }

.transform{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-color: #fe960f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="java.js" defer></script>
    <title>DESING</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="item">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i thought about it so i made the transition time 2seconds and tried it , but when i clicked a second time while the first animation was still running it didn't produce this bug

Comment: I see, though I just edited my answer. Take a look please.

Comment: i saw it make senses why it won't happen this way , but still curious to know why it did in the first place

Comment: Its still happening for me. You don't have to click very fast, just time your second click right when the animation is about to finish. My guess is that the transition end event fires, removes the class but you also click exactly at that time and the class is added again; this time theres no animation so there's no new transition end event.